# Replace NaNs in one dataframe column with another dataframe column python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes: `df_session` and `df_session_focus`.
`df_session` has columns `['user_id', 'group', 'start_time', 'end_time']`; `df_session_focus` has columns `['user_id', 'group', 'focus_leave', 'focus_enter']`.

df_session

user_id         group       start_time     end_time

13ai0      control 2020-01-21 20:39:10+00:00    2020-01-21 21:00:02+00:00

13ai0   control         2020-01-22 13:42:31+00:00   2020-01-22 14:12:31+00:00

13ai0   control         2020-01-22 14:13:27+00:00   2020-01-22 14:43:27+00:00

13ai0   control         2020-01-23 00:13:30+00:00   2020-01-23 00:43:30+00:00

I want to replace NaNs in `focus_enter` with values from `end_time`.

I tried existing solutions, but nothing worked for me:

1.

```
d2 = df_session.set_index(cols).end_time.dropna()
df_session_focus.fillna(df_session_focus.focus_enter.join(d2, on=cols))
```

Error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'join'`

2.

```
mapping = df_session.set_index("session_id")
df_session_focus["focus_enter"] = df_session_focus.focus_enter.map(d2['end_time'])
```

Error: `KeyError: 'end_time'`

3.

```
df_session_focus.merge(df_session[["session_id", 'end_time']],left_on="end_time", right_on="end_time",  how="left")
```

Error: `KeyError: 'end_time'`

Comment: Can you add some sample data for explain problem? What means not working?

Comment: Can you paste the error messages you see when using the solutions you've tried?

Comment: does `df_session` and `df_session_focus` has same  `user_id` and `group` ? Or atleast all `user_id` in `df_session` present in `df_session_focus` ?

Comment: `user_id` and `group` are present in `df_session` and `df_session_focus`

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
df = pd.merge(left=df_session_focus, right=df_session, 
              on=['user_id', 'session_id'], how='left')

df['focus_enter'] = df['focus_enter'].fillna(df['end_time'])

finalresult = df.drop(['group_y', 'Unnamed: 0_x', 'Unnamed: 0_y'], axis=1)
finalresult.rename(columns={'group_x':'group'}, inplace=True)
```